# Как записать само дерево в файл в алгоритме Хаффмана?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево, сжатие

Я написал программу которая умеет производить шифрование алгоритмом Хаффмана, но возникла проблема, нужно сохранить само "дерево" в файл для дальнейшей расшифровки(т.к сохранять "дерево" в отдельный файл нет смысла) Так вот, скажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Сохранить в файл, сохранить дерево? В каком именно виде вы его храните в программе? Если я так же "обобщенно" напишу - сохраните все его узлы - вам станет понятно? :) А вопрос вы именно так и задали - как сохранить "вообще"...Тем более что не указан ни язык, ни конкретная структура...

Comment: @Harry при запуске, программа создает дерево и сжимает файл, сейчас дерево я никуда не сохраняю, вот у меня и вопрос как сохранить это самое дерево в сжатый файл. Если что у меня есть эта программа на  github https://github.com/Log1c0/Huffman_Tree (Прошу не ругать за плохой код :) )

Comment: Ну вы же знаете правила - код (вернее, важная его часть) должен быть в вопросе. А в тэгах указан язык. С С# больше, чем я сказал, не подскажу - язык не мой.

Comment: @Harry а хотя бы алгоритм можете подсказать, моя программа работает именно так как я описал выше, так что ничего нового из кода вы бы не узнали

Comment: @Log1c0 А какой именно момент сохранения дерева вы не знаете как сделать ? Сама операция записи в файл такая же как и для основных данных. Значит сложности вызывает что то конкретное в структуре дерева, что в файл просто так не пишется. Вот что именно это такое. И дерево внутри программы можно представить десятком способов и при этом запись дерева может то же отличатся. Поэтому у вас и пытаются уточнить как именно у вас дерево находится в памяти.

Comment: И кстати, если вы имеете ввиду все таки алгоритм сжатия Хаффмана, а не шифрование, то как сказано в описании самого алгоритма для успешного декодирования данных необходимо сохранять таблицу частот. Таблица частот это же вроде не совсем то же самое, что дерево.

Comment: @Mike Мне не понятен момент именно как его сохранить, чтобы потом можно было его считать, может можно эту таблицу отделить от всего остального? Ну например у меня есть строка "ППАААПП" Весь текст я перевожу в биты(чтобы можно было использовать алгоритм не только для текста) получается допустим: `00000000 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000001 00000000 00000000` (Я упростил для примера) Строим дерево и получается такая таблица 00000000-0 00000001-1. Получается сжатый файл `0011100`. Так вот как в этот файл добавить нашу таблицу для того, чтобы все это декодировать?

Comment: В данном случае я бы записал `1П1А'. Где 1 - это байт с двоичным значением длины последующей строки, что бы при чтении было понятно сколько байт дальше означают очередной узел дерева. И пишем строго сначала строку для 0, потом для 1. Когда бит больше опять же порядок следования должен точно говорить что это такое.

Comment: @Mike я вроде понял вашу идею, но хочу быть уверен. Можете привести пример как я сделал выше

Comment: Не понимаю чем ваш пример отличается от моего. Вы же в файл не 0 и 1 в текстовом виде пишите, а байты с указанными двоичными значениями. пишите соответсвенно 4 байта, 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x01

Comment: @Mike Хорошо, оформите пожалуйста как ответ, чтобы я его мог отметить